# Does java web application contains only one hibernate session and how to clear this hibernate session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having an issue in saving and retrieving objects in database in just one request.
I want to clear the cache of our hibernate session to get the updated entity in our database.
My code looks like this:

```
public class SampleController{
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
        myServiceOne.doAllotsOfSaving(parameters);
        //some code enhancements to remove cache in hibernate session
        //without affecting the session of other user logged in.

        //some fields in MyEntity class contains the old values but the actual data in database is already updated

        MyEntity entity = myServiceTwo.getMyEntityByOrderNo(orderNo);
    }
}
--configurations
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <ref local="hibernateProperties"/>
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <ref bean="auditLogInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceOne" class="com.test.service.impl.MyServiceOneImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="myServiceTwo" class="com.test.service.impl.MyServiceTwoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
--configurations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Does java web application contains only one hibernate session and how to clear this hibernate session?***

No any hibernate based application must use multiple sessions. Each of these sessions must be closed when they perform their task. Hibernate can manage sessions for you if you configure the same in hibernate's configuration file.
However you should have only one instance of [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) per application.

To clear the session you can call the [session.clear()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear()) method. It clears the session level cache.

***without affecting the session of other user logged in***

Since you have a web application, you have a different thread for each user for database transactions. This means each user will have a different hibernate session, so you won't have to worry about this. If by some means you're using same session for all the users, you're doing it wrong and results can be catastrophic. After some time you'll get an `OutOfMemoryError` because of session level cache.

You must note that you cannot disable hibernate session level cache. For this purpose you may use [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Session factory` is long live `multithreaded` object.
Usually one `session factory should be created for one database`.

A `Session` is used to get a physical connection with a database. The `Session` object is lightweight and designed to be instantiated each time an interaction is needed with the database.

The main function of the `Session` is to offer `CRUD` operations for instances of mapped entity classes. Instances may exist in one of the following three states at a given point in time:

**transient**: A new instance of a a persistent class which is not associated with a `Session` and has no representation in the database and no identifier value is considered `transient` by `Hibernate`.

**persistent**: You can make a transient instance persistent by associating it with a `Session`. A `persistent` instance has a representation in the database, an identifier value and is associated with a `Session`.

**detached**: Once we close the `Hibernate` Session, the persistent instance will become a `detached` instance.